# JSHint "Possible strict violation." when using `bind`

Tags: javascript, jshint

Consider this simple code:

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    f: function() {
        this.prop = 'value';
        g.bind( this )();
    }
};

function g() {
    console.log( this.prop );
}
```

If I try to validate this code, jshint gives me the error `Possible strict violation.` where I call `console.log( this.prop );`. This is because `this` is undefined in strict mode in a function.

But I'm binding this function before calling it, so `this` is the correct object.

I'm using this "design pattern" to avoid cluttering the main object. Passing the properties in the parameters will also clutter the function, so I refuse to do this. Besides, this is exactly what `bind` is for.

Is there a way for JSHint to let me do this?

Comment: Is this maybe a bug in jshint?

Comment: Well, it's right in the fact that this is a possible strict violation. However, if it can't parse the `bind` matter, I think it should remain a warning, not an error. Dunno...

Comment: But like you have mentioned; this is not an error ***because*** you have bound it *first* before calling it. Having it spew a warning probably isn't too helpful either because this is the intended purpose of `.bind()`

Comment: Yep... I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/621) in the jshint queue, but maybe there's a configuration way to change this? That's why I asked the question: to find a workaround (not too ugly), if any is possible.

Comment: "this is exactly what `bind` is for" - Well, here, you may want to just do `g.call(this)`, I guess. (Not sure if it solves the issue, though.) If you want to bind `g` by default, you could do `var g = function() { }.bind(obj)` instead, that stops jshint with complaining.

Comment: @pimvdb good idea, but I'm afraid it doesn't play well with hoisting (a good advantage of functions).

Comment: In this case, it's obvious what g is bound to. But in general, it can be arbitrarily difficult to determine that, up to the point that it's actually undecidable. 

I suspect  that jshint takes a purposefully simple approach and doesn't try to analyze things that can't be settled by pretty straightforward analysis.

Comment: @user802500 I suggest you read [this issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/621) where one of jshint maintainers is thinking about removing this warning.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It is extremely hard to detect this case without running the code. You can use option `validthis` to suppress this warning:

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    f: function() {
        this.prop = 'value';
        g.bind( this )();
    }
};

function g() {
    /*jshint validthis:true */
    console.log( this.prop );
}
```

It is to be noted that jshint comments are function scoped. So the comment will work for the function `g` and its inner functions, not just the next line.

Comment: Do I have to add this comment before every line where I use `this`?

Comment: No, options in JSHint are function scoped. So this comment will work within function `g` and its inner functions (if any).

Comment: But the dumb thing is that it's not a potential strict mode violation. Declaring a var without the var keyword would be a strict mode violation. This is just the wrong warning for an error that might result from attempting to access a property of undefined. It's a potential strict mode-related problem but the problem would have nothing to do with actually violating strict mode rules.

Comment: Or add **"[validthis](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis)": true** to your .jshintrc

Comment: @Raine this will disable the check for your entire codebase though. This is a special case, and should be handled specifically, not for the whole codebase.

Comment: if you are going to be using this a lot though it may be worth it

Answer (score 7):

You can also achieve the same effect if you modify your code to the following to avoid using `this` all together.

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    f: function() {
        this.prop = 'value';
        g.bind( null, this )();
    }
};

function g(self) {
    console.log( self.prop );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution that doesn't require any change of pattern or specific markup for jshint:

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    f: function() {
        this.prop = 'value';
        G.bind( this )();
    }
};

function G() {
    console.log( this.prop );
}
```

jshint assumes that you're following the convention that functions starting with an uppercase letter are classes which will be instantiated and always having `this` available.

Comment: I think that causes quite a code smell.  You're just using an unrelated feature of jshint to trick it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    f: function() {
        this.prop = 'value';
        g.bind( this )();
    }
};

var g = function() {
    console.log( this.prop );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different "design pattern" as you put it, it achieves the same thing, but avoids the problem entirely.

```
"use strict";

function obj() {
    this.prop = '';
}

obj.prototype.f = function obj_f() {
    this.prop = 'value';
    this.g();
};

obj.prototype.g = function obj_g() {
    console.log( this.prop );
};
```

you would invoke it like thus:

```
var myO = new obj();
myO.f();
```

Comment: I said in my question that I wanted to avoid this pattern :)

Comment: this pattern is only cluttering if all your scripts are in one file, you can use libraries such as require.js to modularise your code.

Comment: Thank you, I know about require.js, webpack, browserify, etc. This is not the matter of this question though.

Comment: +1. This answer may not answer OPs original question, but is useful for others having problems with the "possible strict violation" error.